# dpkg: error: duplicate file trigger interest for filename '/usr/lib/gio/modules' and package 'libglib2.0-0:i386'

Tags: apt, 20.04, dpkg

I am facing a very strange error on my Ubuntu 20.04 anytime I try sudo apt-get upgrade

the following is the error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libldap-2.4-2 libldap-common libsystemd0 libudev1 zlib1g
5 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
16 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/577 kB of archives.
After this operation, 12.3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: error: duplicate file trigger interest for filename '/usr/lib/gio/modules' and package 'libglib2.0-0:i386'
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: I need urgent help to resolve this, please help out

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg  -P libglib2.0-0:i386`

Comment: @nobody that didn't work :(

The error is: 

7dpkg: error: duplicate file trigger interest for filename '/usr/lib/gio/modules' and package 'libglib2.0-0:i386

Comment: Oh, `dpkg -S /usr/lib/gio/modules` any output?

Comment: @nobody I got the error:  dpkg -S /usr/lib/gio/modules
dpkg-query: error: duplicate file trigger interest for filename '/usr/lib/gio/modules' and package 'libglib2.0-0:i386'

Comment: `cat /var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File`  please.

Comment: Followed your instruction but nothing really changed @nobody

Comment: I need output from command

Comment: The output is too long for me to put in a comment

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dpkg: error: duplicate file trigger interest for filename \`/usr/share/icons/hicolor' and package \`hicolor-icon-theme'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/314704/dpkg-error-duplicate-file-trigger-interest-for-filename-usr-share-icons-hico)

Comment: No It does't @nobody

Comment: put output to https://paste.ubuntu.com/   and add link to your question  https://askubuntu.com/posts/1292663/edit

Comment: done now : https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/GBtBmmrfkY @nobody

Comment: remove this `/usr/lib/gio/modules libglib2.0-0:i386/noawait` from the file. `sudo apt -f install`

Comment: @nobody I get the error :dpkg: error: duplicate file trigger interest for filename '/usr/share/glib-2.0/s
chemas' and package 'libglib2.0-0:i386'
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

Comment: I've removed it but there seems to be one more file to be removed, help me out @nobody

Comment: @nobody It was asking me to remove the file: /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas libglib2.0-0:i386 and when do and try sudo apt -f install or sudo apt-get upgrade I get the following errors: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5VZYjrQrxb/

Comment: Save your data and install new

Comment: Wow ;/ hmmmmn @nobody

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exception: cannot get content of ubiquity-frontend-gtk error running python rtupdate hook ubiquity-frontend-gtk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420662/exception-cannot-get-content-of-ubiquity-frontend-gtk-error-running-python-rtup)

Answer (score 0):

Look at /var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File and delete the offending lines.  Back up the "File" as "File.BAK" prior to changing.  This worked for me in Linux Mint 21.1.